# Safari Smart Banner disappears in some iOS 7.1.2 but works in some 7.1.2 devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, smartbanner

I was testing Safari Smart Banner Feature in iOS devices, in Some iOS 7.1.2 smart banner appears and in some devices it disappears. Both are having same version of OS.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me.

I solved the problem by change the Region of App ID.
http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-change-app-store-country-region-in-iphone-or-ipad/

Hope that help you.

Comment: Instead of just giving the link add some Important points from that link to your answer